# Changing the NatTable cell selection color

Tags: java, nattable

When I click on a row, the entire row color changes as expected. However the cell that the mouse is over changes to a different color than the rest of the row.  I am trying to prevent the cell from changing to a color that is different from the rest of the row.

I am trying to figure out where the cell selection color is getting set and how to remove that (let the cell selection use the cells current background color).

I have unsuccessfully tried things like modifying the CellConfigAttribute or unregistering it via:

```
getNatTable().getConfigRegistry().
  unregisterConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE);
```

but no luck.  I have no clue how to iterate over all the styles in order and see where this is generated from.  I would have liked to see an existing  method similar to:

```
List<ConfigAttribute<IStyle>> list = getNatTable().getConfigRegistry().
  getConfigAttributesInOrder();
```

Unfortunately all I see is something like this, which I don't find useful for my situation:

```
List<String> strings = getNatTable().getConfigRegistry().
  getDisplayModeOrdering().getDisplayModeOrdering("SELECT");
```

I have read the documentation which has some general advice but seen no explicit code samples showing how to do this. So, show do I determine where the cell is getting modified and how do I prevent it?

The code I am using for complete row selection is:

```
public void foo() {
    final SelectionLayer selectionLayer = glazedListsGridLayer.
      getBodyLayerStack().getSelectionLayer();
    final RowOnlySelectionConfiguration<T> selectionConfig = 
      new RowOnlySelectionConfiguration<>();
    selectionLayer.addConfiguration(selectionConfig);
    getNatTable().addConfiguration(new RowOnlySelectionBindings());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about the selection anchor. And the only thing you have to do is to register the same style for DisplayMode.SELECT and label SelectionStyleLabels.SELECTION_ANCHOR_STYLE that you register for only DisplayMode.SELECT. The different style is registered in DefaultSelectionStyleConfiguration